# How send keys to a tag via splinter or selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, automation, beautifulsoup, splinter

I a trying to fill a message box which use key press events , Now i am able to find that message box with splinter so normally that message box div is this :

```
       <div aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="js_7" aria-
    describedby="placeholder-cmsmo" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Type
 a message..." class="notranslate _5rpu" contenteditable="true" 
role="combobox" spellcheck="true" tabindex="0" style="outline: none; user-
select: text; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word;"><div data-
contents="true"><div class="" data-block="true" data-editor="cmsmo" data-
offset-key="7qui-0-0"><div data-offset-key="7qui-0-0" class="_1mf _1mj">
<span data-offset-key="7qui-0-0"><br data-text="true"></span></div></div>
</div></div>
```

But when i type something then text goes between `"<span>"text"</span>"` like this :

```
    <div aria-autocomplete="list" aria-controls="js_7" aria-
expanded="false" aria-label="Type a message..." class="notranslate _5rpu"
 contenteditable="true" role="combobox" spellcheck="true" tabindex="0" 
style="outline: none; user-select: text; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: 
break-word;"><div data-contents="true"><div class="" data-block="true" 
data-editor="cmsmo" data-offset-key="98vvu-0-0"><div data-offset-
key="98vvu-0-0" class="_1mf _1mj"><span data-offset-key="98vvu-0-0"><span 
data-text="true">hello this is example text</span></span></div></div></div>
</div>
```

So now i am able to find the span tag like this in python:

```
d ="""//*[@id="actual_id"]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/span"""



span_tag=browser.find_by_xpath(d)




for i in span_tag:
    print(span_tag["data-offset-key"])
```

result :

```
98vvu-0-0
```

So it means i have find the span tag now how to send keys via splinter or selenium to fill between that span tag so auto type in that message box?

I tried these two approach like this :

```
span_tag=browser.find_by_xpath(d1)


span_tag.send_keys("hello this is example")
```

second

```
span_tag=browser.find_by_xpath(d1)




for i in span_tag:
    print(i.send_keys("hello this is example"))
```

But in both case i am  getting this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/splinter/element_list.py", line 72, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.first, name)
AttributeError: 'WebDriverElement' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/dname/Downloads/pythoncrawling/requested1.py", line 53, in <module>
    span_tag.send_keys("hello this is example")
  File "/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/splinter/element_list.py", line 75, in __getattr__
    self.__class__.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'ElementList' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
```

Answer (score 0):

Splinter looks like it's very early in development and doesn't have all the apis you'd expect to get from the normal selenium python APIs (including send_keys). I would ditch Splinter and just use the normal bindings if I were you.

http://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/driver-and-element-api.html#elementapi

No mention of send_keys here or any of the other apis for other objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
span_tag.first._element.send_keys(...)
```

references the internal Selenium element.